# Calling a Bash script variable from the commandline

Tags: arrays, bash, command-line, arguments

I have a Bash script that accepts a command-line argument. The script defines a couple of string arrays. The argument determines which array(s) I would like to print. Since there are a bunch of different possible sets of arrays to choose from, I would like to be able to specify on the command-line exactly which arrays to print.

For example, say I define these arrays:

```
#/bin/bash
myarray1=(abc 123)
myarray2=(def 456)
myarray3=(ghi 789)
myarray4=(jkl 012)
myarray5=(mno 345)
myarray6=(pqr 678)
myarray7=(stu 901)
```

I would like to choose from the command-line whether or not I want to print all the arrays, or various combinations of these arrays, such as `myarray1`, `myarray3`, and `myarray4`. But on another run, I only want to print `myarray5` and `myarray7`.

I would ideally like to be able to run the script like this:

```
np ~/usr-bin > bash myscript.bash myarray1 myarray3 myarray4
```

So that the output is this:

```
abc 123
ghi 789
jkl 012
```

Or like this:

```
np ~/usr-bin > bash myscript.bash myarray5 myarray7
```

So that the output is this:

```
mno 345
stu 901
```

I'd like Bash to take these arguments and recognize that they're array/variable names, and then print them as if I were doing this: `echo $1`

I have barely done any Bash scripting before, and the method I've tried to accomplish this with doesn't seem to work. Is this something that's possible, or is there a much better way to accomplish this than the way I'm trying to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Bash 4.3 (2014-02-26), you can use namerefs as a simple solution:

```
print_arrays() {
  for a in "$@"; do
    # This makes _t_ an alias for the variable whose name is $a
    declare -n _t_="$a"
    echo "${_t_[@]}"
  done
}
```

Prior to 4.3, you need to use the `!` indirection syntax. However, the variable indirected through needs to contain the *entire array reference*, including subscripts. And you can only indirect through a variable, not a string expression. So you'd need to do something like this:

```
print_arrays() {
  for a in "$@"; do
    # Construct the "name", which is the subscripted array name
    _t_=${a}[@]
    echo "${!_t_}"
  done
}
```

If you're new to Bash, you should read the [Bash manual section on arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays), which explains the curious syntax `"${array[@]}"`. The definition here of `_t_` is intended to create that syntax; it is not itself a subscript expression.

Comment: I was getting an error running your first example, but I entirely forgot that the version of bash on this machine is 4.1, not 4.3. Your second example did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Bash versions - 3.0: 2004-07-27, 4.0: 2009-02-20, 4.1: 2010-05, [4.2: 2011-02](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html#AEN21220). [Shellshock patch 4.3.027 on 2014-10-01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)#Patches). What's the (release) date for 4.3?

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a level of indirection to variable expansion by using `!`:

```
#/bin/bash

myarray1=(abc 123)
myarray2=(def 456)
myarray3=(ghi 789)
myarray4=(jkl 012)
myarray5=(mno 345)
myarray6=(pqr 678)
myarray7=(stu 901)

for i in $*; do
    echo ${!i}
done
```

Running that with `testscript myarray6 myarray2` will output:

```
pqr
def
```

If you want to make sure it doesn't give you blank lines for variables that don't exist, you can use:

```
#/bin/bash

myarray1=(abc 123)
myarray2=(def 456)
myarray3=(ghi 789)
myarray4=(jkl 012)
myarray5=(mno 345)
myarray6=(pqr 678)
myarray7=(stu 901)

for i in $*; do
    if [[ ! -z "${!i}" ]]; then
        echo ${!i}
    fi
done
```

Running that with `testscript myarray6 xyzzy_plugh myarray2` will *still* output:

```
pqr
def
```

(assuming you don't have an environment variable called `xyzzy_plugh` but, unless you're a Colossal Caves fan, why would you?).

Comment: is there a way to have this solution print both (all) of the items in the array? If that's possible, this is the ideal solution to my problem.